# Basic: What is the proper way to push a new GraphQL model into Amplify? (ELI5)

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm, aws-amplify, aws-cli, aws-amplify-cli

I want to upload a GraphQL model made by Amplify Studio's data manager into another app hosted in Amplify studio. I am unclear how to do this using VS code and Amplify CLI. I believe a step by step guide on how to push Amplify Studio's incomplete resource into the production environment would be helpful.

I think the issue is that I don't know how to navigate Amplify's folders and resources within Cloudshell or VSCode - which appears to be such a simple problem that there's no text on it.

I copied a GraphQL model from another Amplify Studio app within Amplify Studio's data manager. In a new app staging environment I want to upload this same GraphQL model without having to redo the model visually.

When I attempt to to do so through Cloudshell's AWS Amplify CLI it prompts me to use VS Code and navigate to the GraphQL file. I do not know how to navigate VS Code to get to the GraphQL file. I've attempted to connect VS code to my amplify staging environment using AWS toolkit, but the Explorer doesn't show my Amplify App or its directories.

I am able to change the resources directly on AppSync after making the tables visually, but the changes aren't pushed throughout the environment - prompting me that this is not the proper way to change the model. This appears to be a simple problem but the documentation gives me no direction on how to do this without having redo our complex data model structure.